# Transitive references in .Net Core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, transitive-dependency

While developing a sample web app in .NET Core 1.1 and Visual Studio 2017 RC, I realized the following:

[image]

As you can see:

- ClassLibrary3 has a reference to ClassLibrary2,
- and ClassLibrary2 has a reference to ClassLibrary1

I wrote a simple method in class Class3 of ClassLibrary3 project, and the Intellisense allowed me to use Class1 just writing the name of the class, I mean, without doing an explicit reference to ClassLibrary1 project.

Am I missing some point here? I don't want somebody simply comes and overlooks ClassLibrary2.

Thanks.

Comment: ClassLibrary1 is included in ClassLibrary3 due to the fact that it is needed by ClassLibrary2, so of course Class1 is available there.  You just need to add `using ClassLibrary` as it says.  You may need to clarify what your goal is - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I can't remember if previous versions of Visual Studio/.NET worked like that. I think it was mandatory to reference directly a project to be able to use its elements, not just having a transitive reference.

Comment: I found a possible solution for this question: https://ardalis.com/avoid-referencing-infrastructure-in-visual-studio-solutions

Comment: .NET Framework projects do not work like this. In .NET Framework, if A references B and B references C, that doesn't mean A references C. They changed this in .NET Core projects. I don't like this because A may not want to use C. The other day, a coworker accidentally used an extension method in a NuGet package that his project **did not** reference, a method named after something in Linq.Enumerable. ReSharper offered to "import missing references in file" so the coworker never saw the unexpected namespace. Plus, in theory, A's build can break if C creates a name collision somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Transitive project-to-project references are a new feature of Visual Studio 2017 and Microsoft.NET.Sdk. This is intentional behavior.

See https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/200.

Comment: Nice. I suppose that now it will be more clear the dependency that UI layers have on Data layers in traditional 3-layered architectures.

Comment: How is a UI supposed to get access to data if it doesn't at some point have a dependency on the data layer?

Answer (score 11):

If you're interested in disabling the transitive reference behavior, I finally found a way.

If you want Project A to reference B and B to reference C, but don't want A to reference C, you can add `PrivateAssets="All"` to B's ProjectReference to C, like so:

**In B.csproj**

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\C\C.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This setting makes C's reference private so it only exists within B. Now projects that reference B will no longer also reference C.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2313

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

1. In **ClassLibrary1.csproj** use `DisableTransitiveProjectReferences` property

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
       <PropertyGroup>
           <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
           <DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <ItemGroup>
           <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibraryCore2\ClassLibraryCore2.csproj" />
       </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
2. In **ClassLibrary2.csproj** use `PrivateAssets="All"`

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
       <PropertyGroup>
           <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <ItemGroup>
           <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibraryCore3\ClassLibraryCore3.csproj" 
               PrivateAssets="All" />
       </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```

I explained the difference more in other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60852224/350384).