# Why is .net core allowing assembly access through project dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Consider this setup in .net framework projects/assemblies:

- layer3 (.net framework console app) references Layer2
- Layer2 (.net framework library) references Layer1
- Layer1 (.net framework library) references nothing

Now when I try to access Layer1 from Layer3, it won't allow me:

[image]

> The type or namespace name 'Layer1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This makes sense.

Now when I create the same setup in .net standard projects and a .net core console app, like so:

- layer3 (.net core console app) references Layer2
- Layer2 (.net standard library) references Layer1
- Layer1 (.net standard library) references nothing

I am able to to this, and compile just fine:

[image]

Which makes no sense to me.

Is this by design? How do I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: And another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428571/transitive-references-in-net-core-1-1/42431299#42431299

Comment: Right, so this is by design. Guess I googled for the wrong keywords..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, turns out this is by design and the workaround is this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibraryA\ClassLibraryA.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />  
  </ItemGroup>
```

[See also this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2313)