# Difference between .Net Framework and .Net Core Project Reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I was working in .Net Framework and Now I learn ASP.Net Core I Have Some Doubt. I Have a one Web App/API Project and Two Class Libraries(Services and Communication ). In Communication Layer Referred with Service Layer. In that Communication Layer Referred in Web Layer.

In a Communication Layer Classes Access in Web Layer. It's Possible For .Net Framework.but not able access Service layer in Web Layer Because, It's Not Referred in Web Layer.

In the same Structure was Created in a ASP.Net Core 2.0 Application. In a Service Layer Also Accessible in Web Layer.

How the web layer access the service layer without reference of service layer.

.Net Core Reference Image

[image]

.Net Framework Reference Image

[image]

i was working in .Net Framework for more than 3 year's. i know the service layer class not directly access without reference. for code separation and access only reference layered only access in the web layer. that layer communicate other layer based on the reference.

in this .net core access directly. in this scenario how to how to access secure and separate the layers. and one layer communicate only reference layer.

I think In .Net core access the All Reference in . Hierarchical of All Layer.

Any One Know share the Solution.

Thanks

Comment: This is a new feature called "Transtive references" -  see this question [Transitive references in .Net Core 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428571/transitive-references-in-net-core-1-1)

Comment: Thanks @RB. before i don't know it's technical name. now i know it's name and how to stop this Transtive references

Comment: @RB Any Other Features Like this in .Net Core. Please share links. Thanks

Comment: Whether the reference is explicit or indirect, your project still has a depedency on that service layer, and you'll end up with a DLL for it in your build, so it really doesn't matter either way.